# Retrieve different string every day on firebase - swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, date

Sorry if some post already exists about this, but here is what I'm trying to do:

- I have a game for iOS (developed with swift and firebase);
- I'd like to give clues for every day, during a long time. I may change these clues;
- Therefore, my firebase would associate a day with the sentence of the day.

How do I retrieve one string for the day it's associated, since I wouldn't like to code locally sentences in a way that I have always to make a new version in the app store just to change those minimum details? Thank you for any help or alternative suggestions!

Comment: As mentioned in the answer you could leverage Firebase Schedule functions or more   low level cron job to trigger a cloud function. See [The Firebase Blog: Cloud Functions with Cron jobs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, Jay, that's an excelent material!

Answer (score 1):

The more firebase-ish way to created a "Sentences" collection of...

```
{ sentence: 'some sentence', unused: true }
```

[Once a day](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), search it, like...

```
db.collection('Sentences').where('unused', true)  // returns a promise with results
```

Choose a random element from `results.docs` and save it in a "SentenceDuJour" collection

```
let docs = results.docs
let doc = docs[Math.floor(Math.random() * docs.length)]

doc.ref.update({ unused: false })
db.collection('SentenceDuJour').doc('alwaysthesamedocid').set(doc.data())
```

Comment: I'm so, so thankful! That's exactly what I was looking and you answered so fast. Thank you!